# Raising errors in After Triggers Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I raise an error in an AFTER UPDATE trigger in Sql Server 2005, will that cause the update which caused the trigger to be fired to roll back, even if the statement was not executed within a transaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to rollback transaction by calling `ROLLBACK TRAN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_au_table
ON  dbo.table
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
GO
```

This example will prevent from updating any record.

This:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_au_table
ON  dbo.table
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('This is a test', 16, 1)
END
GO
```

will only raise the error but the change will be made in the table.

Comment: So, is there an implicit transaction? If I have not begun a transaction explicitly, will ROLLBACK TRAN cause any issues? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is an implicit transaction. Update and trigger are closed in one transaction. Trigger is always in one transaction with DML or DDL statement. If you perform an UPDATE you have to wait until the statements in the trigger are finished. RAISERROR does not rollback transaction.

Comment: Noting that any rollback statement (without listing a savepoint) will rollback all existing open transactions.  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11469663).