# Does a rollback inside a INSERT AFTER or UPDATE AFTER trigger rollback the entire transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

Does a rollback inside a INSERT AFTER or an UPDATE AFTER trigger rollback the entire transaction or just the current row that is the reason for trigger, and is it same with Commit ?

I tried to check it through my current projects code which uses MSTDC for transactions, and it appears as if though the complete transaction is aborted.

If a Rollback in the trigger does rollback the entire transaction, is there a workaround for  to restrict it just the current rows.

I found a link for [sybase](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/49241;pt=49055) on this, but nothing on sql server

Comment: Doe SQL Server really allow a `rollback` in a trigger?

Comment: I guess it does, b'coz i wrote one, and it didn't throw any error when executing the script and the trigger is working too.

Comment: Why is that scary, i find it useful to avoid duplicate records in a table(a bit complex one to implement using `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX` as it selects on many tables and calls to UDF), although it is not working as per my plan

Comment: A trigger should not be able to control the "surrounding" transaction. That should all under the control of the process running the original statement. It might break the way the process expects things to work. What if the caller decides to rollback the transaction for another reason and the trigger has silently committed part of the work?

Comment: I'm not sure about the commit and rollback, that is the reason i asked the question, anyway i guess, a rollback might be useful to stop irrelevant data(based on complex business requirements, that is where i'm coming from) from entering the table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it will rollback the entire transaction.

It's all in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (see Remarks). Note the comment I've emphasised - that's pretty important I would say!!

> If a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is issued in a trigger:
>
> All data modifications made to that point in the current transaction
>   are rolled back, including any made by the trigger.
>
> **The trigger continues executing any remaining statements** after the
>   ROLLBACK statement. If any of these statements modify data, the
>   modifications are not rolled back. No nested triggers are fired by the
>   execution of these remaining statements.
>
> The statements in the batch after the statement that fired the trigger
>   are not executed.

Comment: Why would you need a workaround?  A trigger is just code like any other code - you control exactly where you want to do rollbacks at all times.

Comment: I think what he is asking is to rollback just the rows involved with the insert/update statement that invoked the trigger.  To do that, I would guess one would need to set a savepoint in the caller, call the insert/update, from side the trigger raise an error based on some logic if needed, then in the caller catch the error and rollback to the savepoint.  I didn't try it though.  A better design (exception free) might be to check the condition in the caller and not even attempt to insert/update those rows in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already been let to know, the ROLLBACK command can't possibly be modified/tuned so that it only roll back the statements issued by the trigger.

If you do need a way to "rollback" actions performed by the trigger only, you could,
as a workaround, consider modifying your trigger in such a way that before performing the actions, the trigger makes sure those actions do not produce exceptional situations that would cause the entire transaction to rollback.

For instance, if your trigger inserts rows, add a check to make sure the new rows do not violate e.g. unique constraints (or foreign key constraints), something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TableA
  WHERE …  /* a condition to test if a row or rows you are about
              to insert aren't going to violate any constraint */
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TableA …
END;
```

Or, if your trigger deletes rows, check if it doesn't attempt to delete rows referenced by other tables (in which case you typically need to know beforehand which tables *might* reference the rows):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE …
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM TableC WHERE …
)
AND …
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM TableA WHERE …
END
```

Similarly, you'd need to make checks for update statements, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Any rollback command will roll back everything till the @@trancount is 0 unless you specify some savepoints and it doesnt matter where you put rollback tran command.

The best way is to look into the code once again and confirm business requirement and see why do you need a rollback in trigger?