# Can't delete from a table inside a trigger

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I'm building this DB about the University for one of my course classes and I'm trying to create a trigger that doesn't allow for a professor to be under 21yo.

I have a Person class and then a Professor subclass.

What I want to happen is, you create a Person object, then a Professor object using that Person object's id, but, if the Person is under 21yo, delete this Professor object, then delete the Person object.

Everything works fine up until the "delete the Person object" part where this doesn't happen and I'm not sure why. Any help?

This is the sqlite code I have:

````
AFTER INSERT ON Professor
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN strftime('%J', 'now') - strftime('%J', (SELECT dateOfBirth from Person WHERE personId = NEW.personId)) < 7665 -- 21 years in days
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ROLLBACK, 'Professor cant be under 21');
    DELETE FROM Person WHERE (personId= new.personId);

END;```
````

Comment: Generally we would wrap this type of logic that affects multiple tables and records inside a Stored Procedure, rather than a trigger.

Comment: Are there any messages or feedback from the console? I expect that you might be encountering an error stating there is no transaction, so the _delete_ line never gets executed due to execution being aborted.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, I haven't learned Procedures yet, so I'm not expected to use them. Also, the console doesn't give me any feedback. I've setup a test for the trigger and found out that the DELETE doesn't work because of it.

Comment: I genuinely hope that no _teacher_ is instructing you to delete from inside a trigger that is aborting the change... This is NOT a standard database logic pattern. The trigger can disallow the `INSERT`, but it should not then _also_ go and delete other records in other tables.

Comment: No, they aren't. They just thought the basic stuff and left us to explore the rest. We had the idea to do it this way, not knowing it was bad.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a SP, your script to insert should check first before inserting the `Professor` record and the trigger should prevent the action as it validates the data, but it should not be deleting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common issue is that there many not be a current transaction scope to rollback to, which would result in this error:

```
Error: cannot rollback - no transaction is active
```

If that occurs, then the trigger execution will be aborted and the delete never executed.

If *ROLLBACK* does succeed, then this creates a paradox, by rolling back to before the trigger was executed in a strictly ACID environment it would not be valid to continue executing the rest of this trigger, because the `INSERT` never actually occurred. To avoid this state of ambiguity, any call to `RAISE()` that is *NOT* `IGNORE` will abort the processing of the trigger.

> **[CREATE TRIGGER - The RAISE()](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#raise)**
> When one of `RAISE(ROLLBACK,...)`, `RAISE(ABORT,...)` or `RAISE(FAIL,...)` is called during trigger-program execution, the specified [`ON CONFLICT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) processing is performed **and the current query terminates.** An error code of [`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`](https://sqlite.org/rescode.html#constraint) is returned to the application, along with the specified error message.
>
> > **NOTE:** This behaviour is different to some other RDBMS, for instance see [this explanation on MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469663/1690217) where execution will specifically continue in the trigger.

As OP does not provide calling code that demonstrates the scenario it is worth mentioning that in SQLite on `RAISE(ROLLBACK,)`

> If no transaction is active (other than the implied transaction that is created on every command) then the `ROLLBACK` resolution algorithm **works the same as the `ABORT` algorithm.**

Generally, if you wanted to Create a `Person` and then a `Professor` as a single operation, you would Create a `Stored Procedure` that would validate the inputs first, preventing the original insert at the start.

To maintain referential integrity, even if an SP is used, you could still add a check constraint on the `Professor` record or raise an *ABORT* from a *BEFORE* trigger to prevent the INSERT from occurring in the first place:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON Professor
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN strftime('%J', 'now') - strftime('%J', (SELECT dateOfBirth from Person WHERE personId = NEW.personId)) < 7665 -- 21 years in days
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Professor can''t be under 21');
END
```

This way it is up to the calling process to manage how to handle the error. The *ABORT* can be caught in the calling logic and would effectively result in rolling back the outer transaction, but the point is that the calling logic should handle negative side effects. As a general rule triggers that cascade logic should only perform positive side effects, that is to say they should only affect data if the inserted row succeeds. In this case we are rolling back the insert, so it becomes hard to identify why the `Person` would be deleted.

Comment: The ROLLBACK succeeds, as the Professor with that id is no longer in the DB, and it isn't rolling back to a point before the Person with that id was created because that Person is still in the DB. Then, when DELETE is called, that Person should be deleted, but isn't, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I've added a link to the docs, the DELETE _is never called_ and that is why the person is not deleted. There should be some error feedback in the console to confirm that the trigger was aborted.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't any console feedback, I don't know why. Any clue as to why I don't get feedback?

Comment: That's a different question, I don't know what CLI, GUI or language runtime you are using,  might need to be enabled. Sounds like a good question to post in your class forum or to ask your tutor.